# Grails 3 development IDE set up

Tags: eclipse, grails, intellij-idea, netbeans, groovy

I am new to grails and using grails 3.3.1 and I am in the way on setting up the development environment.

I am expecting a free IDE to provide full built-in features for Grails like **Intellij Ultimate Edition** or **Groovy/Grails Tool Suite** (only support Grails 2).

I have try and search online tutorial on setting up Grails 3 development environment with Intellij Community Edition, Eclipse and Netbeans but neither of the set up provide full features of Grails Development as of Intellij ultimate edition and Groovy/Grails Tool Suite.

Might need some help over here on suggestion of free IDE to use for development for Grails 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use IntelliJ IDEA to develop applications in grails 3 and there is very good material explaining its use.

In this link https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/webinar-recording-why-intellij-idea-is-the-premier-ide-for-grails-3/ Jeff Brown co-founder of grails gave a comprehensive overview of the Grails 3 support in IntelliJ IDEA (both Community and Ultimate.)

You can also check this [quickast](http://guides.grails.org/grails-quickcasts-developing-grails-3-applications-with-intellij-idea/guide/index.html) named Developing Grails 3 Applications with IntelliJ IDEA.

If you prefer to read there is a start guide on this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-grails-3.html)

I hope it is useful for you

Note apart. You do not really need an IDE to program in grails myself work with sublime text, the console and the documentation for years and I have had a good experience.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be "NetBeans IDE". It is quite easy to setup and it's useful. 
I am using grails 3.3.0, it works perfectly.

**Download Java with NetBeans**
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

**NetBeans Only**
- https://netbeans.org/downloads/

*Remember to select the NetBeans version that support Groovy ( Which support all )*

**Guide on NetBeans**
- https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/groovy-quickstart.html

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: You can have a look of the link below. It is a link from the official website. (http://grails.asia/grails-3-tutorial-setup-your-windows-development-environment/)